# Using the Inserted Value To Return A String From Lookup Sql

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which inserts a customer into a SQL Server Database:

```
@Name varchar(50),
@Country int,
@DateRegistered datetime, 
@NumberOfEmployees int,
@ID int output,

AS

INSERT INTO AccountManagementChristian.dbo.Customer(Name, CountryID, DateRegistered, EmployeeRangeID)
VALUES(@Name, @Country, @DateRegistered, @NumberOfEmployees)
SET @ID = @@IDENTITY
```

I also have a look up table with the Country ID and Country Name and another lookup table with the EmployeeRange ID and the Number of Employees. Both Country Name and Number of Employees are strings.

When inserting I need to be able to return the country name string that corresponds to the country ID that is inserted and the same for the Country Name and Country ID?

Comment: NOTE: You should be using `SCOPE_IDENTITY` rather than `@@IDENTITY` in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you right you need to insert the customer information in the stored procedure input variables then return the details for the newly inserted customer. In which case your `INSERT` for customer is right and instead of having an `OUTPUT` for the customer ID you need to `SELECT` the fields you want as in a normal select. The following should do what you want...

```sql
@Name varchar(50),
@Country int,
@DateRegistered datetime, 
@NumberOfEmployees int

AS

DECLARE @ID INT -- moved this to be a standard variable

INSERT INTO AccountManagementChristian.dbo.Customer(Name, CountryID, 
             DateRegistered, EmployeeRangeID)
VALUES(@Name, @Country, @DateRegistered, @NumberOfEmployees)
SET @ID = @@IDENTITY

-- added this select to return the information you want, 
-- using the @ID value to get details for the new customer
SELECT C.ID AS CustomerID, C.Name, 
       CL.ID AS CountryID, CL.CountryName,  
       ER.ID AS EmployeeRangeID, ER.NumberOfEmployees --, other fields required
FROM   AccountManagementChristian.dbo.Customer AS C INNER JOIN
       CountryLookup AS CL ON C.Country = CL.ID INNER JOIN
       EmployeeRange AS ER ON C.EmployeeRangeID = ER.ID
WHERE  C.ID = @ID
```

Answer (score 1):

I am struggling to really understand where the "Insert Country return" option is coming in, since there is nothing here related to that.  If you are, in fact, inserting the country and then using it, then just replicate the DECLARE @CustomerTab AND the OUTPUT INSERTED rows to catch that data.  The updated script inserts the data and returns the fields I think you are asking for.  Hope it helps.  Below:

```
@Name varchar(50),
@Country int,
@DateRegistered datetime, 
@NumberOfEmployees int,
@ID int output

AS   

DECLARE @CustomerTab            AS Table (CustomerID      INT)

INSERT INTO AccountManagementChristian.dbo.Customer(Name, CountryID, DateRegistered, EmployeeRangeID)
    OUTPUT
        INSERTED.ID INTO @CustomerTab(CustomerId)
VALUES(@Name, @Country, @DateRegistered, @NumberOfEmployees)
--SET @ID = @@IDENTITY

select 
    Customer.Id
    ,Country.ID
    ,Country.[Country Name]
    ,EmployeeRange.[Number of Employees]
from 
    Customer
inner join 
    @CustomerTab CustomerTab 
on
    Customer.Id = CustomerTab.CustomerID
inner join
    Country
on
    Customer.CountryId = Country.Id
inner join
    EmployeeRange
on
    Customer.EmployeeRangeID = EmployeeRange.ID
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick response! I get an error of incorrect syntax near DECLARE @CountryTab AS Table (@Country int)

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure InsertCustomer, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near '@Country'.

Comment: Needed to alias the temp table. - fixed.